# how to select entire tableviewer row when checkbox clicked (first column of the table has checkboxes in each row)

Tags: java, swt, tableviewer

am beginner to SWT, anyone please help,
 my problem is:
i have a table, which has 10 Columns,
the first column has Check box and the rest of the column are filled from Database,
when i check the checkbox i want that perticular row to be selected,

i am pasting my table code below,

```
    public static void main(String arg[])
    {
      // shell and display declared here

            mainTable = new TableViewer(content,  SWT.H_SCROLL| SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.BORDER |SWT.DM_FILL_BACKGROUND|SWT.FULL_SELECTION);

            mainTable .getTable().setHeaderVisible(true);
            mainTable .getTable().setLinesVisible(true);
            mainTable .setContentProvider(new ArrayContentProvider());    

            // COLUM FOR PLACING THE CHECK BOXES
            TableColumn columncOL=new TableColumn(mainTable .getTable(),SWT.NONE);
            columncOL.setText("");
            columncOL.setWidth(40);

            TableViewerColumn columnaC=new TableViewerColumn(mainTable ,columncOL);
            columnaC.setLabelProvider(new ColumnLabelProvider(){

            Map<Object, Button> buttons = new HashMap<Object, Button>();
            @Override
                public void update(ViewerCell cell) {

                    TableItem item = (TableItem) cell.getItem();
                            Button button;
                            if(buttons.containsKey(cell.getElement()))
                            {
                                button = buttons.get(cell.getElement());
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                button = new Button((Composite) cell.getViewerRow().getControl(),SWT.CHECK);

                                String s = "Item 1";

                                button.setData(s, "Some other info or object here");
                                s = "Item 2";

                                button.setData(s, "This is item two");
                                //buttons.put(cell.getElement(), button);
                            }
                            TableEditor editor = new TableEditor(item.getParent());
                            editor.grabHorizontal  = true;
                            editor.grabVertical = true;
                            editor.setEditor(button , item, cell.getColumnIndex());
                            editor.layout();
                        }

                    });

                    // CREATING 1st COLUMNS
            TableColumn column1Head=new TableColumn(mainTable.getTable(),SWT.NONE);
                    column1Head.setText("col1");
                    column1Head.setWidth(200);
                    // setting column input
            TableViewerColumn column1=new TableViewerColumn(mainTable,column1Head);
                    column1.setLabelProvider(new ColumnLabelProvider()
                    {
                        public String getText(Object Element)
                        {
                            Student ap=(Student )Element;
                            return ap.col1();
                        }
                    });

    }
```

like this am creating remaing 8 columns
i want to select the entire row when a perticluar check box checked .
    any one pleeeease help me As early as possible....

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using `CheckboxTableViewer`?

Comment: greg, actually i dont about CheckboxTableViewer. how can i use it? can i use instead of Tableviewer? or ? can u give a small example....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `CheckboxTableViewer` to show a table with check boxes:

```
mainTable = CheckboxTableViewer.newCheckList(content, SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.BORDER | SWT.FULL_SELECTION);
```

To select the line when a check box is ticked you will need to use `addCheckStateListener` to select the checked row, something like:

```
mainTable.addCheckStateListener(new ICheckStateListener()
 {
   @Override
   public void checkStateChanged(CheckStateChangedEvent event)
   {
     if (event.getChecked())
       mainTable.setSelection(new StructuredSelection(event.getObject()));
   }
 });
```

Comment: CheckboxTableViewer mainTable = new CheckboxTableViewer(content,  SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.BORDER | SWT.FULL_SELECTION); this code giving me an Warning that "The Constructor CehckboxTableViewer(Composite,int)is deprecated".   and a cross bar on the checkboxTableViewer.... what should i do?

Comment: Sorry, I was forgetting `CheckboxTableViewer.newCheckList` is the approved way to construct the viewer. Answer updated.

Comment: greg, one more thing please, how to get "Row index or values in the row of selected Checkbox"... please Help me..... thanks in advance

Comment: The `event.getObject()` returns the object that your content provider provides for the row - so it is the object in the input array.

Answer (score 1):

> Easy way :first column of the table has checkboxes in each row can
>   selected or not

---

```
CheckboxTableViewer tableViewer = CheckboxTableViewer.newCheckList(parent, SWT.BORDER | SWT.FULL_SELECTION);
Table table = tableViewer.getTable();
table.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event e) {
             Table table = (Table) e.widget;
                TableItem item = table.getItem(table.getSelectionIndex());
                for (int col = 0; col < table.getColumnCount(); col++)
                {
                    //Table_Column Checked or Not
                    if(item.getChecked())
                        //return true
                        //all ready checked(true) to change unchecked(false)
                        item.setChecked(false);
                    else
                        //unchecked(false) to checked(true) each row
                        item.setChecked(true);  
                }
        }           
    }
```

this is useful for you....thanks